# Is it possible to build a URL with Yahoo Pipes by using a feed title? (item.title)

Tags: url-rewriting, rss, title, yahoo-pipes

Using Yahoo Pipes, I know that there are many ways to take something from a string and insert it into a feed.  I am wondering if it is possible the otherway around.  So far I have been unsuccessful in taking something for instance an title (item.title) and turning it into a string.

What I want to accomplish is taking words from an RSS description and placing them into an url. For the URL Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Fetch feed module to get the raw feed.

Then use a loop module, and put a string builder inside it.  Make the source in the string builder be item.description.  If there are other parts you want to concatenate together with it, add those in to the string builder as well. Assign that value to item.link (or wherever you want it).

You can repeat the loop with a regular expression inside it if you need to process the URL further.

Comment: But can I then take that item.link and use it in a fetch feed?

Comment: Yes, you could connect it to a fetch module.